# How do I Store input data into more than one matrices in Python(without numpy)

Tags: python, file, matrix, input

I have a text file that contains more than one matrix like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXD22.png)

I want to read this input file in python and store it in multiple matrices like:

matrixA = [...] # first matrix

matrixB = [...] # second matrix

...

so on. I know how to read external files in python but don't know how to divide this input file in multiple matrices, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a matrix of matrixes (also called a 2D matrix), and so on.

If you want to put all the input matrixes inside of a matrix you would do

```
Matrixes = [][]

Matrixes[0] = matrixA
Matrixes[1] = matrixB
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the total number of matrices *n* from the first line. For each iteration in *n* read using *readline()* till you encounter the matrix metadata triplet which is in the format *(isalpha(), isnumeric(), isnumeric())*. You can extract the name, the number of rows and columns and then traverse the following matrix through a for loop. Do this each time you encounter the above matrix metadata triplet.

Something like this

```
for each_matrix in n:
    name, rows, cols = 'A', 3, 3
    for _ in range(rows): 
        each_row = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))[:cols] # take space-separated rows of length cols
        matrix_A.append(each_row) # append each row to the matrix
```